# Field of formal power series is complete

Tags: number-theory, analysis, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading Cassels & Frohlich's book *Algebraic Number Theory*. On page 2, it has the following example:

> Let $F$ be a field and let $K$ be the field of formal series
>   $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nt^n$$ where $a_n \in F$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have a standard discrete valuation $v$ of $K$ given by $$v(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nt^n):=\inf \{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a_n \neq 0\}$$ $K$ is complete in the valuation topology.

**Can anyone explain to me why is $K$ complete?**

Comment: The ring of Formal series is $F[[t]]= \{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n, a_n \in F\}$, it is clearly complete for the absolute value $|\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_nt^n| = 2^{-N}$ for $a_N \ne 0$. Then show $1+t F[[t]]\subset F[[t]]^\times$ to obtain $F[[t]][t^{-1}]= \{ \sum_{n=-M}^{\infty}a_nt^n, a_n \in F\}$ is a field which is complete for $|.|$.

Comment: @reuns, can we prove this by using the definition? That is, every Cauchy sequence in the field of formal series is convergent.

Comment: Sure, if $(s_k)$ is Cauchy then $|s_k-s_m| \le 2^{-j}$ implies $s_k,s_m$ agree  up  to the coefficient of $t^j$.

Comment: @reuns, I figured that out yesterday. Thank you for answering my questions!